# SAP Business One B1 - Invalid Item [66000-3] Error

Tags: c#, sapb1

I am having this error when I click on the AR Invoice menu is SAP B1 on a client's server.

[image]

However, when I run it on my local machine, where I developed it, there is no such error.

Below is the section where the error is thrown:

```
static void SBO_Application_ItemEvent(string FormUID, ref SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent pVal, out bool BubbleEvent)
        {
            BubbleEvent = true;

            // Capture invoice form details on Add/Update button press
            if (pVal.FormTypeEx == "133" && pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_ITEM_PRESSED && pVal.ItemUID == "Item_0" && pVal.BeforeAction == true && pVal.FormMode != 0)
            {
```

On the first line, somehow FormUID shows F_25 as soon as the menu for AR invoice is clicked. No such error on my machine.

How do I fix this problem?

SAP 10 Versions for both.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you modife Ar invoice form? If yes make sure that b1s file is genenrated when you build your project and it's copied to production environment.